# How do I provide proper arguments for a class?

Tags: python, class, call

I have this code I am playing with but have no idea on how to call it?

```
class Slide:
  def __init__(self, pictureFile, soundFile):
    self.picture - makePicture(pictureFile)
    self.sound = makeSound(soundFile)

  def show(self):
    show (self.picture)
    blockingPlay(self.sound)
```

Can I not just do pictureFile = "xxxx.jpg", soundFile = "xxxx.wav" and then go show(pictureFile, soundFile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could do either.  The question comes down to when you want to provide the class instance with that information, at the time it's created (in which case you'd put it in the constructor: `__init__`) or at the time you want to show it (in which case you'd pass them as arguments to the show method).

Without knowing the details of your slide project, it seems like it would make the most sense (of the two options) to put it in the constructor.

But those are not your only two options.  You could do neither and do something like:

```
class Slide:

    picture = None
    sound = None

    def __init__(self):
        # Nothing here
        pass

    def setPicture(self, pic):
        self.picture = pic

    def setSound(self, snd):
        self.sound = snd

    def show(self):
       show (self.picture)
       blockingPlay(self.sound)

# "Main"
s = Slide()
s.setPicture("foo.jpg")
s.setSound("bar.wav")
s.show()
```

Which gives you the flexibility of creating a slide without a picture and sound (what if you wanted a blank slide without any music?).

EDIT:  Either you edited your question, or I completely misread it initially.  If I misread it, then Antimony is correct, you'd call that code with what he proposed or something like:

```
s = Slide("foo.jpg", "bar.wav")
s.show()
```

But if this is something you're playing around with to learn programming / python, I think you should think about where the best place to provide your class instances with these arguments is.  At least in your case, I'm not sure that it is the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there's a typo in the code. That - should be a =.

Anyway, the way to call it is

```
Slide("xxxx.jpg","xxxx.wav").show()
```